# problem with display the Range calendar Dates in React js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Hi I am creating RangeDate calendar for my requirement.Calendar is working perfectly. But when i submitting the dates it will displaying some number like 1,234,245,45,679. For example I selecting 01-10-2019 to 12-10-2019  [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkztr.png)

When I submitting the dates it will be displaying like this
[After submitting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bGkH.png)

Why it showing numbers. How to displaying date type like 01-10-2019 to 12-10-2019.Please help me . I blocked 2 days.

My code is

```
    class RangeCalender extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const date = new Date()
    const startDate = date.getTime()
    this.state = {
      startDate, // Today
      endDate: new Date(startDate).setDate(date.getDate() + 6) // Today + 6 days
       };
     }
   onChange = (startDate, endDate) => this.setState({ startDate, endDate })

   sendData = (newMessage) => {
     addUserMessage(this.state.startDate.toLocaleString())
     console.log(this.state.startDate.toLocaleString());
   }
   render = () => {
    const {trigger, startDate, endDate } = this.state
    return (
        <div>
          <ReactLightCalendar startDate={startDate} endDate={endDate} onChange={this.onChange} range 
            displayTime />
          <button class = "Rcbutton"  onClick={() => this.sendData()}>Submit </button>
        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Actually i am new to React js. Please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing numbers because the date stored as a [UNIX timestamp](https://www.epochconverter.com). To show it as date you need to convert it to a date format.

The reason why UNIX timestamps are so widely used is because they can represent all time zones at once.

There are many ways of doing this conversion. Personally I use [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment) for most of my date handling in ReactJS.

Using momentjs you do something like this:

```
var dateAsString = moment.unix(value).format("MM-DD-YYYY");
```

Hope this helps you past this issue.

Comment: var dateAsString = moment(value).formate("DD-MM-YYYY") it is working. Thank you for replying. Thank you soo much

Comment: If you are happy with the answer, feel free to accept it as the correct answer. :)